# instalacion de bootstrap 4 en php por achivos

Tags: bootstrap-4

Parte única en donde de anexan las rutas para instalar bootstrap de manera local:

Anexado de estilos de bootstrap:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >
```

Declaración de los scripts a utilizar:

```
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>

    </head>
```

error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
        at util.js:55
        at bootstrap.min.js:6
        at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

No encuentro el por que me da el error en esa propiedad?. Que solución me pueden dar o aconsejar.

Comment: Es probable que el problema se deba al orden en que estas incluyendo los `scripts`. Primero debería ir `jquery` y luego `Bootstrap` (_el cual requiere al anterior_)

Comment: Repetir preguntas es algo que no esta bien visto y puede llevar al sistema a que te prohiba preguntar por un tiempo. por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegurate de tener primero el jquery instanciado antes que el bootstrap.js y de instalar el popper de bootstrap

Comment: gracias ya no me da errores amigo.